# How to put the output of command in bash variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to put the output of command in bash variable and then further use that variable in other command

Suppose i want something like this

`ls | $(variable) |awk '/$variable/{print "here"}'`

Comment: you need a better example problem. The current one doesn't make any sense. We really need to see 1. sample input, 2. required output, 3. actual output, 4. code that you've tried **to solve a real problem**. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
variable=$(ls); awk "/$variable/"'{print "here"}'
```

Note 1: `/$variable/` is surrounded by double quotes, otherwise it won't be replaced by output of command.

Note 2: The above command may fail since the output of `ls` may contains "/" or newline, which will break the `awk` command. You may change `ls` to something like `ls | tr '\n' ' ' | tr -d '/' | sed 's/ *$//g'`(replace all newlines with spaces; delete all slashes; remove the trailing whitespace), depending on your goal.

Note 3: to avoid variable assignment polluting the current shell's environment, you can wrap the above command by parentheses, i.e. `(variable=$(some_command); awk "/$variable/"'{print "here"}')`

Answer (score 2):

To put command output into variable you can use following format in bash

```
variable=`pwd`
echo $variable
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that you can easily do it in a single step like that, but I don't know why you'd pipe it to `awk` *and* use it in the script like that anyway.  Here's the two step version, but I'm not really sure what it *does*:

```
variable=$(ls)
echo ${variable} | awk "/${variable}/{printf \"here\"}"
```

Comment: Acutally i would like to do it in single line. is there any way

Comment: Well, you could put a `;`.  Why does it need to be a single pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

Or

```
now=`date`
```

Back ticks

Which is easier for me since it works in any shell or perl

Comment: Backticks are equivalent to modern `$(command substitution)` syntax in the trivial case, but are _less_ easy to use in the nontrivial case. The argument that they work in Perl too is a poor consolation when you run into complications. This syntax is obsolescent in the shell for a reason.